# Composite Primary Key and Secondary Covering Index: Does the Secondary Index Ever Need to Include a Primary-Key Column?

Tags: mysql, index, innodb

MySQL. InnoDB.

Say there's a composite primary key 'a, b'. There is another column 'c.' I have a query hitting 'a, c.' Consider two claims. (A) "A secondary index on 'c' gets me a covering index." (B) "A secondary index on 'a, c' is required to cover."

Which is true?

For background, InnoDB adds the primary key to every secondary index.

Comment: What's your take on this? How do you define the term "covering index"?

Comment: Definition of "covering index": "A covering index is an index that contains all the columns in the SELECT. It is special in that the SELECT can be completed by looking only at the INDEX BTree." Source: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#_covering_indexes

My take is mostly a guess. I'd like to avoid guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Covering; yes, "A".  Useful; it depends.  The effective secondary index will be `(c,a,b)`, in that order.

That is "covering" for a `SELECT` that contains *only* a,b,c in any combination and any arrangement.

But that index may not *otherwise* useful.

```
WHERE c=32   -- the secondary index will probably be used, even if not covering
WHERE a=12   -- will prefer the PK
WHERE b=22   -- can't use that index for filtering, but may be able to "cover".
WHERE a > 55 AND c > 55  -- may use `c` part of secondary, or `a` part of PK
WHERE DATA(c) = CURDATE()  -- will scan whole index (cf "sargable")
```

etc, etc

InnoDB includes the PK columns' values (`a,b` in your case) in each secondary key's BTree so that it can locate the entire row in the data's BTree.

(The above info os correct for InnoDB, but not for MyISAM.)

**Leftmost vs Covering**

The **leftmost rule** says that, when evaluating `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY`, only the leftmost columns will be used.  Once a column (in the index) is encountered that is not useful, the ordering and lookup capabilities of the index are mostly ignore.

```
WHERE b = 888 AND c = 999
```

will use only the `c` part of `INDEX(c,a,b)`.  This is because all the rows with `c=999` are nicely next to each other in the index.  But the `b=888` rows are sprinkled among them.

**Covering** focuses on a different technique.

The data is stored in a BTree (see Wikipedia) ordered by the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Each 'secondary' index is stored in a different BTree, but ordered according to the column(s) of the secondary index plus the PK column(s).  That is, think of your `INDEX(c)` as being a BTree ordered by `c,a,b`.  The purpose of `a,b` so so that any other columns you might need can be fetched by using `a,b` to lookup the full rows in the data BTree.

If only those 3 columns are needed by the query, the index is called "covering".  This avoids the extra step of reaching into the other data BTree for other columns.  That extra step is the expense that is saved by "covering".

Note that "leftmost" cares about the order of the columns; "covering" does not care".  Either or both *might* come into play in any particular query.

(I just made up that term.)  Suppose you have:

```
SELECT d FROM tbl WHERE c = 123
```

For efficient lookup, you need `INDEX(c)`.  For that matter, any index *starting with* `c` will make that `WHERE` efficient.

To make a "covering" index, notice that only `d` and `c` exist in the query.  So, `INDEX(d,c)` or `INDEX(c,d)` or even `INDEX(x,y,d,c)` would be covering.

Putting the two together:

```
INDEX(c, d)  -- is optimal
```

or

```
INDEX(c, d, ...) -- You may have other queries that would benefit from this.
```

Another example:

```
SELECT *        -- may as well forget about "covering"
    FROM tbl
    WHERE user_id = 888
    ORDER BY post_date DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

This query is beautiful because it gives an example of where even the `LIMIT` can be handled by the index:

```
INDEX(user_id,     -- is a simple "=" and completely handles the WHERE
      post_date)   -- the index can be used for ordering
                   -- it can stop after 10 items  :)
```

Comment: Thanks. Does the answer change if the query hits only 'b, c'? If the effective secondary index is 'c, a, b', will I have a leftmost-key-constraint problem with a query for 'b, c'?

Comment: @JackAdder999 - b and c in the Select -- `INDEX(c,a,b)` would be covering, but only not very useful.  An index _starting with_ both b and c (in either order) would be better.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm looking again at the MySQL docs on multiple-column indexes and I think I'm confusing the covering-index issue with the leftmost-key issue. The former concerns the SELECT and the latter the WHERE, right? So, effective INDEX(c,a,b) would be covering but SELECT * WHERE b=something, c=something would not use the index in the lookup and so would not be useful, right? effective INDEX(b,c,a) would be useful. So, if I had WHERE b=something, c=something and also WHERE a=something, c=something, I'd want to add INDEX(b,c) and INDEX(c). Did I get this right?

Comment: That's probably right.  I added a bunch of text.